# Python: while loop doesn't loop

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a card came in python and in creating my draft() function used for drafting the player a deck I encountered a problem with my while loop.

I can't seem to figure out why the while loop doesn't loop.

If anyone can figure out why please do let me know.

```
player_deck = []

#draft function to draft a player deck should be used when starting game
def draft():
    while len(player_deck) < 10:
        random_variable = random.random()
        if random_variable < 0.2:
            print("Your choise is between Drake and Recovery")
            print("--->   " + drake.description)
            print("--->   " + recovery.description)
            player_choice = input("Which do you choose: ")
            if player_choice.lower() == "drake":
                player_deck.append(drake)
            if player_choice.lower() == "recovery":
                player_deck.append(recovery)
            else:
                return "Please pick one of the two"
        if random_variable >= 0.2 and random_variable <= 0.999999:
            print("Your choise is between Blast Cone and Eminem")
            print("--->   " + blast_cone.description)
            print("--->   " + eminem.description)
            player_choice = input("Which do you choose: ")
            if player_choice.lower() == "blast cone":
                player_deck.append(blast_cone)
            if player_choice.lower() == "eminem":
                player_deck.append(eminem)
            else:
                return "Please pick one of the two"
        return player_deck

print(draft())
```

Comment: What does it mean *the while loop doesn't loop*? also there are many undefined variables here. Please work out a [mre]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The loop as shown is entered.

Comment: There was an answer that was deleted that pointed to another problem with your code, which is that the `if` checks for `player_choice` should be changed to `if/elif/else`. Right now your function will return if the player chooses the first option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while` loop does not repeat because the last `return` exits the loop before it has a chance to repeat:

```
def draft():
    while len(player_deck) < 10:
        # bla
        # bla 
        return player_deck

print(draft())
```

I assume you wanted indent the `return` differently, maybe

```
def draft():
    while len(player_deck) < 10:
        # bla
        # bla 
    return player_deck

print(draft())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` statement is inside he while loop. As soon as python hits it, the function ends. It should be moved outside of the `while` loop. Here is the code:

```
player_deck = []

#draft function to draft a player deck should be used when starting game
def draft():
    while len(player_deck) < 10:
        random_variable = random.random()
        if random_variable < 0.2:
            print("Your choise is between Drake and Recovery")
            print("--->   " + drake.description)
            print("--->   " + recovery.description)
            player_choice = input("Which do you choose: ")
            if player_choice.lower() == "drake":
                player_deck.append(drake)
            if player_choice.lower() == "recovery":
                player_deck.append(recovery)
            else:
                return "Please pick one of the two"
        if random_variable >= 0.2 and random_variable <= 0.999999:
            print("Your choise is between Blast Cone and Eminem")
            print("--->   " + blast_cone.description)
            print("--->   " + eminem.description)
            player_choice = input("Which do you choose: ")
            if player_choice.lower() == "blast cone":
                player_deck.append(blast_cone)
            if player_choice.lower() == "eminem":
                player_deck.append(eminem)
            else:
                return "Please pick one of the two"
    return player_deck
```